# Classification of finite affine group schemes of order $2$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, group-schemes

Assume $G=\text{Spec}A$ is a group scheme of order $2$ over a ring $R$, I think it is well-known that these group schemes are $G_{a,b}=\text{Spec}\frac{R[T]}{T^2+aT}$ where $ab=2, a,b\in R$, and the group law is $T\rightarrow U+V+bUV$.

But when I see a proof of this, why does it assume $A=\frac{R[T]}{T^2+\alpha T+\beta}$ at first? I remember the definition of the order is rank of $\mathcal{O}_G$ as a locally free module sheaf over $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}R}$.

Thanks !

Comment: Some of your assumptions mean $A$ is a $R$-algebra of dimension $2$ ie. $A = R[T]/(T^2+bT+a)$

Comment: @reuns Sorry, but I get nothing from your hints...And your "dimension" should be "rank" because $A$ is just a commutative ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is an $R$-algebra of rank $2$, then it has an $R$-basis of size 2. Since $A$ is an algebra with unit, we can take one of these elements to be the unit $1$ of $A$, and call the other element $T$. When multiplying elements, we will have $T^2 = aT + b1$ for some $a, b \in R$, simply because $T^2$ is again an element of $A$. This is why the proof is starting off by assuming that $A = R[T] / (T^2 - aT - b)$ or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to know is that if $\mathcal{O}_G$ is a locally free module sheaf over $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}R}$ of rank $2$, then how to prove $A$ is an free $R$ algebra of rank $2$.

Comment: Sorry, I think maybe my definition of the order of a finite group scheme is wrong.